# How to Repackage a SharePoint WSP

Tags: 2013, solution-package

I have branding.wsp file.

I have rename that wsp to cab and extract all the files.

Then I have make some changes in that files.

Now I'm trying to  Repackage a SharePoint WSP

I don't know how to do that.

Please guide me with this.

Comment: https://wspbuilder.codeplex.com/

Comment: http://academy.bindtuning.com/how-to-manually-edit-a-sharepoint-wsp-file/

Comment: depend on what's the changes that you have did ! check the same thread at https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/0dd0bf72-638a-4840-9540-f6d0307bb786/how-to-edit-existing-wsp?forum=sharepointdevelopmentlegacy

Answer (score 2):

First download your WSP file from the solution gallery. Let’s call it “SiteWebsite.wsp”.

Start Visual Studio and Launch the Visual Studio 2012 New Project wizard.

From the list of SharePoint project templates, select the one called: “Import SharePoint 2010 Solution Package”.

Choose a project name and location to store the solution. It’s nice to leave the “Create directory for solution” option selected. Your project name should be the same as the desired name of the final wsp file. We will name our project “SiteWebsite”. Press OK.

[image]

You will be asked if you want to “Deploy as a sandboxed solution” or “Deploy as a farm solution”. Since my original WSP was built as a farm solution, I choose farm.

You will be asked to browse to the existing wsp. Do that.

You will now need to select the specific items from the package that you want to import. All items are selected by default. Confirm that this is so and press OK.
[image]

The selected items will be imported (depending on the size of your project and the number of artifacts contained, this may take quite a while). When done, you will receive a completion message. Press OK and project will now open.